# How to trigger click event from inside iframe element using angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my code snippet i have one iframe which loads another url. From this i need to trigger a method at outside of iframe based on clicking the button from inside iframe using angular2. Also need to get the data from inside iframe. Can anyone provide a solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

**Use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**

**app.component.ts**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ncs-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  src;   
  constructor() { 
    //Yes, is  the same page.
    this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://localhost:4201');    
    //listen for post messages for this url
    window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage, false);
  }

  receiveMessage(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  click() {
    //post message to http://localhost:4201
    window.postMessage('asdasd', 'http://localhost:4201');
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button class="button" (click)="click()" >

</button>
<iframe #iframe id="tcsFrame"
        [src]="src"
        scrolling="no"
        frameBorder="0"
        width="100%"
        height="32000px"
        type='text/html'>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the content in the iframe you can use window.opener to get to the original window. So what you can do is following:

1. You register a function on the window object of your angular app.
2. You use window.opener in the iframe to call said callback.

**1. Register function**

Somewhere in your angular code you need to register a callback function on the window object:

```
// Run this method to setup the iframe callback
setupCallback() {
    window.iframeCallback = (param: any) => this.actualCallback(param);
}

// This method will be executed when you
actualCallback(param: any) {
    console.log('Callback executed:', param);
}
```

**2. Call the function from your iframe**

Then in your iframe you can use following javascript:

```
window.opener.iframeCallback('Hello World');
```